# Web User Control Asp.net

Tags: html, jquery, css, asp.net, webusercontrol

I would like to use a user control with slide toggle on the same page several times.
But, all three don't work the same way.
If I add a user control to the page, everything works fine but if I insert two of them, they don't work correctly. Below is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button').click(function (e) {
        $('#list').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.button {
    width: 200px;
    background: #23997a;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
}

.list {
    width: 200px;
    background: #6bceb4;
    display: none;
}

.buttonList {
    border: none;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00);
    outline: none;
}

#list ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 180%
}


.list ul li:hover {
    background: #ff0000
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button" class="button">
</div>
<div id="list" class="list">
    <ul>
        <li id="li1">
            <input type="button" value="Coffee" class="buttonList" />
        </li>
        <li id="li2">
            <input type="button" value="Milk" class="buttonList" />
        </li>
        <li id="li3">
            <input type="button" value="Juice" class="buttonList" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If I add two or more of this user controls to the page, it doesn't work properly. What should I do to make this correct?

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Custom_Control_Asp.WebForm1" %>
  <%@ Register Src="~/WebUserControl1.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="WebUserControl1" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head runat="server">
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
          <uc1:WebUserControl1 runat="server" ID="WebUserControl1" />
          <uc1:WebUserControl1 runat="server" ID="WebUserControl2" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What would happen with the ID's `button` and `list` if you add more than one control...

Comment: I can't understand ...

Comment: As suggested I solved using ClientId ... Thanks!